# App:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED duplicate entry

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Good Day i am doing FireBase Cloud Notification and i will be getting

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zza.class

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "aminfocraft.harsh.firebasenotificationdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
}
```

./gradlew clean also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

should be outside of dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'    
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1**

call  **`apply plugin properly`**

**Problem 2**

Add **`play-services:10.2.1`**

Try this way

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "aminfocraft.harsh.firebasenotificationdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

should be outside of `dependencies`

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'    
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also you forgot to add the play services dependencies..

add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'`

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

should be outside of dependencies

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'    
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also you forgot to add the play services dependencies..
add

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1`'